VBA error - This network connection has files open or requests pending
I have a macro which runs in Thisworkbook - Workbook_BeforeClose and it should unmap network drive. This network drive is mapped when this workbook is opened and the path is the location of this workbook. Error happens on line: objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive MappedDrive
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object
Dim objFd As FileDialog

    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If FS.DriveExists(MappedDrive) Then
        ChDrive "C"
        ChDir "C:\"
        Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive MappedDrive
    End If

I tried to redirect drive and directory, this did not help:
    ChDrive "C"
    ChDir "C:\"

I tried unmap another network drive (not current which is created when the excel is opened), this is working, but i need to unmap the drive which is created at the beginning.
objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive "A:"

Instead of using a (temporary) mapped drive, have you tried to work with UNC-pathes?
